# Bold a single grid line in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the ZERO gridline bold?

[image: Bold Gridline]

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with, including sample data and code. You said a bold gridline, but then show a box around that line; what exactly are you trying to get? This is why an attempt at code is helpful

Comment: If you just want one line to be bold, I recommend just using `geom_hline` or `geom_vline` and plot them before any other `geom_*` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain about what you want without a reproducible example, but an easy solution could be by simply using `geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "grey", size=2)`. Of course you can change the color or size.

Answer (score 1):

As @JustinLandis says, something like

```r
geom_hline(yintercept=0,lwd=3)
```

should work (adjust the value of `lwd` to your liking; you can also specify this as `size`).
Since `ggplot` plots in order, put this specification *before* your `geom_line()` and other stuff.